# Got my datepicker widget setting the right format....now validation on django form fails

Tags: django, datepicker

I have a form (rendered with crispy forms) I define in forms.py:

```
class Meta:
    model=HousingRequest

    fields = ('off_site_location', 'notes', 'checkin_date', 'checkout_date', 'purpose_of_visit', 'project_for_visit')

    widgets = {
      #'room' : TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'1', 'placeholder':'Trainee First Name'}),      
      #'user' : TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'1', 'placeholder':'Trainee First Name'}),   #these are really already from who is logged in?
      #'male': TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'3', 'placeholder':'Trainee''s Institution'}),  #we might get this from who is logged in also
      'off_site_location' : TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'4', 'placeholder':'Offsite location'}),
      'off_site_phone' : TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'5', 'placeholder':'Contact Phone'}),
      'notes' : TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'5', 'placeholder':'notes'}),

      'checkin_date':DateInput(attrs={
          'class':'datepicker form-control',
          'tabindex' : '6',
          'placeholder' : 'Checkin Date MM/DD/YYYY',          
          'autocomplete':'off',
      }, format='%b %d, %Y'),

 ...etc...
```

The format I set is to be:
Oct 25, 2019

Great.  My date picker now returns this format (when on another form it was returning 10/25/2019)
it is defined in my base.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function() {
      var j = jQuery.noConflict();    
      j('.dateinput').datepicker({ dateFormat: "M dd, yy" });
    });

  </script>
```

Okay, so I click in the field, date picker comes up.  Select it bam I get:

Oct 25, 2019

I goto save the form the field says 'Enter a valid date'.

No idea where or why the validation is failing.

The whole reason for this is on another form using a simple:

```
<td> {{ hou.checkin_date}} </td>
```

It kept displaying as Oct 25, 2019 on load (from the django object passed to the template)

Which when the date picker was called on that (via javascript) it would replace that date with 10/25/2019 and it was jarring (the piece sent back via ajax saved just fine with no validation errors).   So now I updated that datepicker above to have the format specified Oct 25, 2019 so my ajaxy form thats just displaying the hou.checkin_date works great! Looks great...

now an older form broke with the data validation described in the widgets above...

So not sure why  it keeps saying invalid date.

Comment: `%Y` is **xxxx**, while you are using `yy` which will return **xx**. Isn't that the issue?

Comment: no according to https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate, yy is a 4 year date.

Comment: Additionally, I typed into the field 1/2/2020 and it worked just fine got past the validation.  Seems like it isn't accepting the format that is defined in the forms.py